# Want to forcely enable Pjax in IE9 in yii2

Tags: yii2, pjax

Some here now, I am in such situation that I need to use Pjax for IE9 in yii2.As I already proceed with many Pjax forms ..reverting back to ajax is not a good option for me.. Anywhere can help me .. for this..

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work in IE < 10. So have to use jquery .ajax function and make a server request.

Comment: It works by adding <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/history.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]--> in head